# Problem with default parameter and object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a problem with default parameters in Javascript.
I have a function like this:

```js
function search(filterOptions = {
    foo: 'bar',
    foo2: 'bar2'
}) {
  ...
}
```

When I call  `search()` without arguments, `filterOptions` is set to `{foo: 'bar', foo2: 'bar'}`,
but when I call `search({ foo: 'something' })`, `foo2` is undefined.

I cannot separate `filterOptions` into several arguments because options are independent.

How can i make `foo2` take its default value anyway (and cleanly)?

(I'm on nodejs)

Thank you!

Comment: Your parameter is filterOptions and not foo2. Add a validation step like `if(!filterOptions.foo2) filterOptions.foo2 = ''` would be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You could define the defaults within the function and use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to combine the two objects, which will override the defaults where applicable.

```js
function search(filterOptions) {
  const defaults = { foo: 'foo', foo2: 'bar' };
  filterOptions = {...defaults,...filterOptions};
  console.log(filterOptions);
}

search({foo: 'something'});
```

Comment: @RomainC I've added a link to the relevant portion of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide default values in the parameter list:

```js
    function search({ foo = "bar", foo2 = "bar2"} = {}) {
      console.log("foo is " + foo + ", foo2 is " + foo2);
    }

    console.log(search());
    console.log(search({ foo: "broccoli" }));
    console.log(search({ foo: "my foo", foo2: "my foo2" }));
```

The `= {}` at the end is to handle the case when the function is called with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the default variable with an `if` statement:

```
function search(arr) {
    if(arr.bar === undefined) {
      arr.bar = "bar1";
    }
    //do whatever
}
```

The use of **`===`** is to make sure that the `if` does not run if bar is set to `"undefined"` (a string).